# SQL Azure Import Error - Operand type clash: image is incompatible with geography

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

**My database contains a table with Geography column having spatial data.**

Importing its .bacpac (Data-tier App) on SQL Azure Standard fails without giving any proper error details.

**Tried a direct Data Export using wizard and received an error:**

Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "**Operand type clash: image is incompatible with geography**".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

**Any idea why Geography is a problem here?**

---

### Update

I recently upgraded SSMS to 2016 and this error has gone. It must have been due to older version of SSMS that didn't support import export of spatial data.

Comment: bacpac validates everything ,say for example you have dropped a table which references a view,while importing,you will get error and import will not succeed.Posting  some more info on question like the table schema will help

Comment: It's interesting you're getting this through SSIS. Are you sure you're not using the separate, SSIS-based migration to Azure wizard rather than using a bacpac? For instance bacpacs use ADO.Net, not OLE DB. Adding the exact steps used will help diagnose the root cause.

Comment: @Kevin Cunnane - Inporting bacpac just fails on Azure. I did not put much time in searching for error logs on Azure. So tried Data Import Export wizard through SSMS and received the above error. So finally, I dropped the newly inserted geography (spatial) column from the table and exported the data. And then added the new column through script directly on Azure DB table.

Comment: To clarify, did you get this error through SSIS or SSMS? Also, were you successful on that last attempt (when you dropped the column and re-added after you imported the database)?

Comment: @nnuemah - SSMS and yes I could import without spatial column and then updated the table by re-adding it using sql query.